# How to count series of continuous values in Excel

Tags: excel, count, binary, continuous

I was hoping you could help me with this (relatively) simple problem.. I have a dataset in Excel where a column, let's say A5:A605, is a series of binary values - only ones and zeros.

Now I want to know two things:

1. How many times is there a "set" of zeros? So I need to know the frequency, but also counting f.e. 20 zeros as one.
2. What is the longest "set" of zeros?

To make it a bit clearer, the following range:

0
0
0
0
1
1
0
1
1
1
0
0
1
0
0
0
0
0
1
1

Should give me the answers:

1. **4** (because there are four sets of zeros) and
2. **5** (because that is the longest continuous set of zeros)

As a bonus it would be nice if it could also indicate where the longest continuous set, but this is not entirely necessary.

I hope someone can help me!

---

Thanks in advance,
Renske

Answer (score 0):

Will this work?

```
Sub marine()
Dim row As Long
Dim countstreak As Long
Dim count As Long
Dim col As Long
Dim nzeroes As Long
Dim lzero As Long
Dim nzeroescol As Long
Dim lzerocol As Long
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim i As Long

'Configuration
col = 1 '1 is for column A, change here in case you need
nzeroescol = 2 'Which column it will show the number of sets of zeroes
lzerocol = 3 'Which column it will show the longest set of zeroes
lastrow = 605 'Last row of your data. You can make it automatic by changing 605 to "Cells(Rows.count,col).end(xlup).row" no quotes

For row = 5 To lastrow 'Change the 5 to the starting row of your data if needed
    For i = 1 To Len(Cells(row, col))
        If Mid(Cells(row, col), i, 1) = "0" Then
            count = 1
            countstreak = countstreak + 1
        ElseIf Mid(Cells(row, col), i, 1) = "1" Then
            nzeroes = nzeroes + count
            If countstreak > lzero Then
                lzero = countstreak
            End If
            countstreak = 0
            count = 0
        End If
    Next i
    Cells(row, nzeroescol) = nzeroes
    Cells(row, lzerocol) = lzero
    nzeroes = 0
    lzero = 0
Next row
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much Moacir! But I'm guessing this should be done in R (or similar) then? I was hoping for something that could be done in Excel itself, maybe some kind of COUNT-function.. If that's not possible I'd like to know as well so I can adjust my work.

Comment: This solution involves using VBA, which is inside Excel. If you use Alt + F11 you should get to the code part.

Comment: However, if you are looking for a "Function only" solution, I can neither give you a solution nor tell you with certain that it cannot be done.